# Should I upload all my R code in figshare before submitting my manuscript?

Tags: paper-submission, data, code, doi

To conduct my study, I had to use thousands of lines of **R code** to generate random data and to do analysis. Now, when I am going to submit my manuscript to my targeted journal, do they ask to provide all the code? As I never submitted any article before, so I don't know what to do!

I have read the instructions from the journal. From there I got to know about **figshare**. Should I upload all my R code there first and then after getting *DOI*, try to submit the manuscript by adding the DOI in the **data availability statement**?

Answer (score 6):

First, this depends on the journal and its data availability policy. The prime arbiter is the editor or associate editor of the journal. You can contact them on what they would find most convenient for their process.

Second, a paper and therefore possibly the data you generated is likely to change during the review process. If you think that your R-code is unlikely to change, you can go ahead and put it in a public repository. Otherwise, you can offer to put the code in a zip file and make it available to the reviewers with your submission as supplementary material. Depending on your paper, reviewers might just believe that you were working appropriately and not used e.g. a flawed random number generator. There are other ways to make the material available to the anonymous reviewers.

Getting a DOI now seems to me to be premature since the contents of your supplementary material might still change.

Comment: The question is about code, which is shared differently from data. Your answer has some good ideas about data sharing, but isn't well focused on the question asked.

Answer (score 4):

I would use GitHub or GitLab to track my code and then issue a DOI once the paper is accepted and the code will no longer be edited (either to a GitHub tag or a figshare page).